# Notepad ++ Line Formatting

Tags: pdf, notepad++, formatting

So I have a transcript open in Notepad++ that was converted from a PDF.

It is laid out like such:

```
00 00 00 01 I have had a very nice day today, i went
to the park to play football
00 00 00 02 It has been a wonderful day.
00 00 00 03 I have rally liked today as it has been
very fun.
```

As you can see from the example text, the sentence has followed below. All of the lines that are the start of each entry start with 00 so i was just wondering if there was a way in notepad ++ to be able to move text onto the same line without having to do this all manually, also there being a space between the word on the correct line.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Search → Replace →

- Find what: `\R([^0-9]+)`
- Replace with: <kbd>Space</kbd>`\1`
- Regular expression in *Search Mode* selected
- *Replace All* button.

Explanation: `\R` new line; `[^0-9]` all but 0-9; `+` repeated `\1` - first `(`group`)` of characters.

Comment: don't you need to put groups in `()`?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes you do. Corrected.